# Finding the dimension of the vector space V and give a basis for V

Tags: linear-algebra

V = {p(x) in P2 : xP'(x) = P(x)}

I let P(x) = a + bx + cx^2
Taking the derivative of this I get P'(x) = b + 2cx

However then xP'(x) does not equal P(x) 
So, do I basically have to keep guessing for P(x) such that xP'(x) = P(x)?

Comment: You need to find the set of polynomials such that that IS true. You can do that algebraically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: equate coefficients. You want to find the set of polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$ such that $$xP'(x) =P(x)$$  $$(2ax+b)x = ax^2+bx+c $$ $$ 2ax^2+bx=ax^2+bx+c$$

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find p'(x) = p(x).  Let p(x)= x so p'(x)=1 and if you multiply x by p'(x) you get x which is p(x). So your dimension is 1 and your basis is x. I have this problem as a homework question and I just figured it out and the webassign indicated it's correct.